# log files are getting messed up (Logs are getting written to multiple same log files at a time)

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We have configured log4j(version 1.2.15) and log4j.properties in our project for different purpose. We are facing an issue with the log files writing. If you look at the below files, they are not in order and the logs are getting written to multiple files at a time. Initially they are looking good, but after sometime its happening and due to this we are not able to debug the issues.

```
web@:/prod/sys/web/vapprev/logs> ls -ltre | grep web

-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024135 Jun 20 11:45:06 2016 webpass.log.10
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024052 Jun 20 11:51:45 2016 webpass.log.9
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024273 Jun 20 13:05:05 2016 webpass.log.8
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024030 Jun 20 13:07:04 2016 webpass.log.7
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024111 Jun 20 13:07:33 2016 webpass.log.6
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1026339 Jun 20 14:54:14 2016 webpass.log.5
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024445 Jun 20 14:54:22 2016 webpass.log.3
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024201 Jun 20 15:30:44 2016 webpass.log.2
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup    1080 Jun 20 15:39:30 2016 webpass.log
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup   66420 Jun 20 15:39:53 2016 webpass.log.4
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup   72414 Jun 20 15:39:54 2016 webpass.log.1



web@pnjdvgnapp1:/prod/sys/web/vapprev/logs> ls -ltre | grep web

-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024135 Jun 20 11:45:06 2016 webpass.log.10
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024052 Jun 20 11:51:45 2016 webpass.log.9
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024273 Jun 20 13:05:05 2016 webpass.log.8
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024030 Jun 20 13:07:04 2016 webpass.log.7
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024111 Jun 20 13:07:33 2016 webpass.log.6
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1026339 Jun 20 14:54:14 2016 webpass.log.5
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024445 Jun 20 14:54:22 2016 webpass.log.3
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup 1024201 Jun 20 15:30:44 2016 webpass.log.2
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup   68580 Jun 20 15:42:53 2016 webpass.log.4
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup   74574 Jun 20 15:42:54 2016 webpass.log.1
-rw-r--r--   1 web webgroup    3600 Jun 20 15:43:00 2016 webpass.log
```

Below is the log4j.properties

```
/vgn-ext-templating.war/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties

****************************************
        ###Product Logs
        log4j.logger.com.vignette.ext.templating.cache=DEBUG, DPMLOG
        log4j.logger.com.vignette.ext.templating.util=DEBUG, DPMLOG
        log4j.logger.com.vignette.ext.templating.taglib=DEBUG, DPMLOG
        log4j.logger.com.vignette.ext.templating.client.javabean=DEBUG, DPMLOG
        log4j.logger.com.vignette.ext.templating.portal.webservice=DEBUG, DPMLOG
        log4j.logger.com.vignette.ext.templating.link=DEBUG, DPMLOG
        log4j.logger.com.vignette.ext.templating.ui.widget.ck=DEBUG, DPMLOG
        log4j.logger.com.vignette.ext.templating=DEBUG, DPMLOG
        log4j.additivity.com.vignette.ext.templating=false
        log4j.logger.com.vignette.vps.dpsext=DEBUG, DPMLOG

        #Webpass application Logs
        log4j.logger.com.test.webpass=DEBUG, DPMLOG
        log4j.additivity.com.test.webpass=false


        # DPMLOG is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
        log4j.appender.DPMLOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
        log4j.appender.DPMLOG.File=${com.vignette.portal.installdir.path}/logs/webpass.log
        log4j.appender.DPMLOG.Append=true
        # added flush property on 05/23/2016
        log4j.appender.DPMLOG.ImmediatFlush=true
        log4j.appender.DPMLOG.Threshold=DEBUG
        log4j.appender.DPMLOG.MaxFileSize=1000KB
        log4j.appender.DPMLOG.MaxBackupIndex=20
        log4j.appender.DPMLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
        #log4j.appender.DPMLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
        log4j.appender.DPMLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c %x - %m%n
****************************************
```

Below is the log4j.xml, but it has nothing to do with above log, as it is configured in the log4j.properties

```
*******************************************
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
        <!-- main resources -->
        <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

          <loggerFactory class="org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLoggerFactory"/>

            <!-- esapi appender : START -->
          <appender name="waffile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="${com.vignette.portal.installdir.path}/logs/templating-esapi.log"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
               <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d[%t]%-5p %m%n"/>
            </layout>
            <param name="Append" value="true"/>
            <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB"/>
            <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20"/>
          </appender>
          <!-- esapi appender : END -->


        <!-- esapi logger  : START-->
          <logger name="org.owasp.esapi">
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <appender-ref ref="waffile" />
          </logger>
         <!-- esapi logger  : END-->


        </log4j:configuration>
**************************************************
```

Below are the steps tried

## Steps already Tried

1) Tried moving all the configurations to log4j.xml and eliminated log4j.properties - Not resolved
2) Upgraded the log4j from log4j-1.2.15 to log4j-1.2.16 - Not resolved

Thanks,
Raju